# what is the general step to solve $f(x)\pm f(g(x))=m(x)$

Tags: calculus

I try with a simple example

I put $$f(x)=2x$$

and $$f(2x)=4x$$

so

$$f(x)-f(2x)=-2x$$

and I try to solve the last equation

$$f(x)-f(2x)=-2x$$

by put $$f(x)=e^{mx}$$

[then the solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20e%5E%28mx%29-e%5E%282mx%29=-2x%20for%20m) $$e^{mx}=\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{2x+\frac{1}{4}}\neq 2x$$

I know that $$e^{mx}-e^{2mx}=\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{2x+\frac{1}{4}}-(\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{2x+\frac{1}{4}})^{2}=-2x$$

but $$\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{2x+\frac{1}{4}}\neq 2x$$

where is the wrong

and any way how to solve equation like $$f(x)\pm f(g(x))=m(x)$$

Comment: Why would you expect $e^{mx}$ would be a general solution? And if $f(x)=e^{mx}$, then $f(f(x))=e^{e^{mx}}\neq e^{2mx}$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: $f(g(x))$ not $f(f(x))$ and $g(x)=2x$

Comment: You never defined $g(x)$, only $f(x)$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: just try to solve the equation I expect $e^{mx}$ is a general solution

Comment: Why would you expect that?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I saw an answer use same way but in a different question

Comment: but is this way wrong ?

Comment: Well, you know the answer is $2x$. Can $f(x)=e^{mx}$ ever by $2x$?  There are times in differential equations where that substitution works, under very narrow conditions, but this is not a differential equation.

Comment: But when solving a functional equation, we are not solving for $x$, we are solving for $f$.  $f(x)-f(2x)=-2x$ must be true for all $x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Andrews now iam understand 
thanks for you but is there a general solution for my question or a way to solve my example ?

Comment: I've given a way to solve your example below, with some very limited assumptions about $f$.  For general $g$ there are no techniques I know of to solve this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this equation is if we assume that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Then we have: $$f(x)=x+f(\frac{x}2) =x+\frac{x}{2} +\frac{x}{4} + \dots + \frac{x}{2^n} + f(\frac{x}{2^n})$$

The limit of the right side as $n\to\infty$ is $f(0)+2x$, which gives the general solution, $f(x)=C+2x$.

The problem with a general $g(x)$ is almost certainly intractable.

Comment: can I talk with you in chat room I need help in a simple question ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm at my work, so I can't chat.

Answer (score 1):

It may seem a good idea to try $y=f(x)=e^{mx}$, since then $f(2x)=e^{2mx}=y^2$ and then you get your quadratic equation from $f(x)-f(2x)=-2x$ in terms of $y$ after rearranging: $$ y^2-y-2x=0.$$
Now *if* $y$ had nothing to do with $x$ this would have the solutions $y=(1/2) \pm \sqrt{2x+1/4}$ which you mention. However when you put $y=e^{mx}$ back into this, you see it cannot lead to a solution, since if it did then the exponential function $e^{mx}$ would be expressed in terms of radicals.